# WPF text box, can't edit text...about to give up

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I have several usercontrols split between separate tabs of a tabcontrol. All of these usercontrols have perfectly functioning textboxes except for one. On this particular control I can't edit values in any of the it's textbox controls.

I can get a cursor in the textbox and can highlight text, but I can't delete or add text. There is nothing special about the UserControl it's in. It's not a pop up window or anything like that (I know that can cause issues).

Is there anything outside of the textbox itself that can cause this problem? I am out of ideas...

```
                    <TextBox  x:Name="SpeedRange3Text" Width="35" Height="20"
                          FontSize="8"
                          Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                          MaxLength="4"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          TextAlignment="Center"
                          Text="{Binding SpeedRange3 }"
                          IsReadOnly="False"
                          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>

    public double SpeedRange3
    {
        get
        {
            return _spdRng_3;
        }

        set
        {
           if (value <= 60 && value >= 0)
            {
                _spdRng_3 = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _spdRng_3 = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a value between 0 and 60");
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("SpeedRange3");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cannot say anything until you provide project with issue reproducible. Although, you can use wpf UI debugging tools in visual studio to check runtime property value and see if somehow IsReadOnly is set from somewhere else inside your app.

Comment: There are only two instances of "IsReadOnly" in the entire solution and they are for two unrelated textboxes. I did do a test by adding IsReadOnly to one of the functional textboxes and the behavior seems to be very similar.

Comment: Did you check runtime IsReadOnly property value of the control? Can you check if some other parent control is listening to key events and cancelling them out?

Comment: I just put a check in and IsReadOnly=false at run time.

Comment: Not sure what you meant but will it be possible for you to share code with reproducible issue?

Comment: Possible cause: the logic behind `SpeedRange3` property. Could you share this part?

Comment: I also added a textbox to the parent usercontrol and that textbox works fine. That particular usercontrol references the usercontrol in question as such: <local:ControlPanel x:Name="SimulatorControlsPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />n as such: <local:ControlPanel x:Name="SimulatorControlsPanel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

Comment: It's a fairly complex project overall, would be hard to strip out just this component unfortunately. Also contains some fairly sensitive data.

Comment: I even tried removing the Binding completely and I still can't edit the value.

Comment: Is the UserControl read only or disabled?

Comment: Have you tried hard coding value in the `TextBox` and remove the `Binding`?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that could cause issues, is if you accidentally add two different elements at the same grid row and column location such that they are overlapping each other. Thus, one element is consuming click events when you try clicking into the `TextBox`. Hitting the tab key may eventually get you to the right element, but you may want to move them apart such that they don't overlap anymore.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that focus remained on some other window in your app. Maybe you should try to get focus on your Window/UserControl

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing some operations on TextChanged event of that textBox,
Add a break point to the TextChanged event in your code , and see what happens. i have also faced similar issue when i type, the event had it cleared. just a guess.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no events, just the binding.

Comment: oh. pardon me!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this old thread hoping that it can help someone, since I finally solved the issue that I had on this.
**In my specific case** the TextBox was inside a DataGrid which had the **IsHitTestVisible** property set to **False**; removing this property solved the issue.

As a clarification this is what I had:

```
<DataGrid IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="False" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And this is the working code:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" IsReadOnly="False" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had very much the same problem. I had a simple `<TextBox>` with a Name and Background attribute, located in a `<Grid>`. Couldn't figure out why it ignored all efforts to take focus and then allow me to enter text.

My solve was to add the `Focusable="True"` attribute to the `<TextBox>` element.

I hope this helps others. I know this is an old question, but it's still relevant today!